# google placeautocomplete view close automatically

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google map api. I used Api Key in my project and also i linked release SHA1 Key. It is working correctly in debug apk, but in release apk place autocompleteview is close automatically. I checked the Logcat, in logcat the api key is different from the key i used in meta-data in android manifest file.

```
   private void manualLocation() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build((Activity) context);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.e("Tag", "Place: " + place.getAddress() + place.getPhoneNumber());
            Log.e("Tag", "Place: " + place.getLatLng() + place.getPlaceTypes());

            if (signup.matches("1")) {
                latitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
                longitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);

        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.e("Tag", status.getStatusMessage());
            locationStatus = "0";
            AppPreferences.savePreferences(Location.this, "locationStatus", locationStatus);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            locationStatus = "0";
            AppPreferences.savePreferences(Location.this, "locationStatus", locationStatus);
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
}
```

I used the key in meta-data "AIzaSyBH9saN7RRHev1QNKWqtIjejojvqJuCswU" but in Logcat the key is different. i show you the Logcat. Can anyone help me?

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/autocompleteWidget?key=AIzaSyBb2MNLJEmWt-FLJqN28D_-WuxQiMwzUhU
```

this is the Logcat response

Comment: add more detail please

Comment: Please check i added some more detail.

Comment: Please post the exact query that you are trying to run., so somebody can try to run it and debug. Generally, error 403 means that [you have exceeded your usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits#http403).